# Change object value based on an array

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to convert an array of selected days into an object conditionally change the value of selected day to 1 but have not figured out it yet. Please give me advice if you experience this.

```
let result = {fruits: "orange", colour: "orange"}
const selectedWeekdays = ['monday', 'tuesday']

let defaultDay = {monday: 0, tuesday: 0, wednesday: 0, thursday: 0, friday: 0,saturday: 0, sunday: 0}

days = Object.keys(defaultDay).map(function (key, index) {
      if (selectedWeekdays.includes(key)) {
         return key = 1
      }
})
```

```
Expected result: 
result = {
  fruits: "orange",
  colour: "orange",
  monday: 1,
  tuesday: 1,
  wednesday: 0,
  thursday: 0,
  friday: 0,
  saturday: 0,
  sunday: 0
}
```

I know that I have to return value but I don't know how to keep the same format as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you're returning the `key = 1` inside `map`, which results numbers `[1, 1, 1, ....]` like this.

> return key = 1 -> which returns `1`

You can try any of these solutions.

```js
const result = {fruits: "orange", colour: "orange"}
const selectedWeekdays = ['monday', 'tuesday']

const defaultDay = { monday: 0, tuesday: 0, wednesday: 0, thursday: 0, friday: 0,saturday: 0, sunday: 0 }

selectedWeekdays.forEach(day => {
   if (defaultDay[day] !== undefined) {
       defaultDay[day] = 1
   }
})

const finalResult = { ...result, ...defaultDay }

console.log(finalResult)
```

```js
const result = {fruits: "orange", colour: "orange"}
const selectedWeekdays = ['monday', 'tuesday']

const defaultDay = { monday: 0, tuesday: 0, wednesday: 0, thursday: 0, friday: 0,saturday: 0, sunday: 0 }

for (const day in defaultDay) {
  result[day] = defaultDay[day]
  if (selectedWeekdays.includes(day)) {
    result[day] = 1
  }
}

console.log(result)
```